# Folder name based on Numeric sort

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like to retrieve the name of a folder which is the highest in numeric order, to be more precise.
All of the folders are named based on some randon 6 digit numbers.

For example:

If I have folders named

1. **123456**
2. **234567**
3. **345678**

Then I would like to be able to assign a variable with the string **345678**
Something like:

```
set highestNumber=<code for highest number>
```

Comment: are the folders really named 100,200,300

Comment: It is actually 6 digit random numbers

Comment: Could the numbers also begin with zeroes?

Comment: No, regular positive integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the option `/O` of the [`dir` command](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) to get a sorted list of folders, walk through that list using a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) and assign the current item to a variable by [`set`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html), which will finally hold the last item:

```cmd
for /F "delims= eol=:" %%D in ('dir /B /A:D /O:N "D:\root\*"') do set "LAST=%%D"
echo(%LAST%
```

This relies on the fact that all folder names consist of the same number of digits.

---

If the folder names are numbers that do not have the same number of digits, and you want the greatest number, `dir /O:N` does not work, because it does alphabetic sorting, where `10` appears before `2`. So you need to change the approach -- here is an example (range `0` to `2147483647`):

```cmd
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Initialise buffer:
set "GRNUMB="
for /F "delims= eol=:" %%D in ('
    rem/ Filter folders for purely numeric names: ^& ^
    dir /B /A:D "D:\root\*" ^| findstr /R /C:"^0$" /C:"^[1-9][0-9]*$"
') do (
    rem // Do numeric comparison:
    if %%D GTR !GRNUMB! set /A "GRNUMB=%%D"
)
rem // Return result:
echo(%GRNUMB%
endlocal
```

The variable `GRNUMB` holds the name of the folder constituting the greatest number encountered so far. As soon as the name of the current folder constitutes a greater number, `GRNUMB` is updated.

---

If the folder names are numbers that do not have the same number of digits and could also begin with zeros, you need to change the code a bit -- here is an example (working for max. 5 digits):

```cmd
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Initialise buffers:
set "GRNAME=" & set /A "GRNUMB=0"
for /F "delims= eol=:" %%D in ('
    rem/ Filter folders for purely numeric names: ^& ^
    dir /B /A:D "D:\root\*" ^| findstr "^[0-9][0-9]*$"
') do (
    rem // Remove leading zeros:
    set "NAME=%%D" & set /A "NUMB=10000%%D, NUMB%%=10000"
    rem // Do numeric comparison:
    if !NUMB! GTR !GRNUMB! set "GRNAME=!NAME!" & set /A "GRNUMB=!NUMB!"
)
rem // Return result:
echo(%GRNAME%
endlocal
```

The variable `GRNAME` holds the name of the folder constituting the greatest number encountered so far, `GRNUMB` holds that number converted to a true integer value<sup>1</sup>. As soon as the name of the current folder constitutes a greater number, both `GRNAME` and `GRNUMB` are updated.

---

<sub>1)  The command `set /A "NUMB=10000%%D, NUMB%%=10000"` precedes `10000`, then divides the result by `10000` and returns the remainder; the effect of this is that leading zeros disappear, which would cause `set /A` and `if` to interpret the numbers as octal integers otherwise unindentionally.</sub>

Comment: This works if the folders contain the same amount of digits, which is absolutely fine, but could it work also for folders with different amount of digits?

Comment: Now yes as I added two more approaches which are capable of handling numeric folder names as true integer values, one can even handle leading zeros which could be problematic in batch scripting...

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but why is there a "(" after the echo command

Comment: No, this is not a silly question! `echo %VAR%` returns `ECHO is on|off.` if `%VAR%` is empty; `echo(%VAR%` is the only safe way to avoid unexpected behaviour; there is a thread on [DosTips](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=774) concerning that issue...